# Python inter-process Queue overflow

Tags: python, queue, producer-consumer, interprocess

I have a producer set-up with N consumers.

The producer listens on a socket which receives a high volume of TCP messages (10,000 per min), reads this data and puts it into the Queue for the workers.

The workers I have set-up to read from the Queue as follows:

```
iterations = 0
work_iterations = 0
while True:
  try:
    iterations += 1
    data = queue.get(block=False)
    work_iterations +=1
    do_work(data)
  except Queue.Empty:
    time.sleep(0.001) #avoid high CPU usage


  if iterations == 100:
    load = float(work_iterations/iterations)
    print load
    iterations = 0
    work_iterations = 0
```

This is simplified code, but you can see I'm trying to see the worker load but see how many iterations out of 100 the worker was actually able to pull work out of the Queue. If the load is consistently 100/100, then I know that the producer/consumer Queue is getting backlogged. Theoretically this *should* work.

What I see in the output is a lot of 0.97, 0.99 and very few 1.0. But the queue does fill up within a few minutes (it has a size limit of 10,000), and I have to start dropping data on the Producer side. Can anyone shine some light on why this is happening? If the worker process is getting work 97/100 iterations on average, that means the Queue should be close to empty no?

Answer (score 0):

When you call queue.get(block=False), then Queue.Empty may be raised even if the queue isn't actually empty. In the event that your current process can't acquire the lock to access the queue, Queue.Empty will be raised no matter how many items are actually in the queue.

A quick look at the Queue.get() code in multiprocessing/queues.py:

```
126    if not self._rlock.acquire(block, timeout):
127        raise Empty
```

Notice that there is no check for how full the queue actually is before raising the exception. Since you have so much information being enqueued, I suspect that the few times Queue.Empty was raised, it was actually caused by the producer holding the lock while enqueueing, causing your worker's attempt to access the queue to fail.

You can check this with a small change to your code:

```
except Queue.Empty:
    print queue.qsize() # returns the approximate number of elements in the queue
```

As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) says, this number isn't perfectly reliable. However, since you're dealing with such large numbers of items in your queue, it should be close enough to tell you if your queue is closer to 0 or 10,000.

Answer (score -1):

What if You remove block=Flase and time.sleep() ?
You will be not able to count workers.